# which software has sorting capabilities to help mastering the fretboard?

Tags: guitar, fretboard

I am looking for software that sorts music elements such a note, an interval, a chord or an arpeggio randomly in a defined period of time, until I stop of the sequence. The idea is to become fluent finding these elements fast, without utilizing visual memory extensively, but knowing exactly where the notes are. I know scales fingerings and play them, but I can't percept which notes I am playing at a given time exactly because is too fast.

Here I try just enforce the knowlegde of the notes on the fretboard. In the software described I don't want to do nothing virtually expect the "randomness" part, evertyhing it would be done by paying the instrument. The idea is just take advantage of the automatic randomness of the computer to develop my fretboard skills.

Comment: Guitar Pro is the only software I use and it has standard music notation which can help you figure out what fret is what note. You can also program it to do everything you're asking. Really though, I don't think you need special software for this. Memorize a few frets at a time, 5, 7 and 12 are a good place to start. The shapes (visual memory) on the guitar are the intervals and will help you memorize chords/arpeggios, etc. Just keep practicing and dedicate your practice time to some of these ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use a software. Learn all the natural tones on the low E string (E / F / G / A / B / C / D ). Play them, slowly, saying their names out loud, ascending and descending. Once you know them, you can learn the flats and sharps.
Then either : 
- do the same on the A string, while keeping on practicing the E string, then the G etc...
- Or you use octave visual shape to know every note on the neck quite rapidly - for example, if you need to know what note is the 10 fret of the D string, visualise an octave shape (there's many of them, the most commonly known is the one you can find in a powerchord) : 8 on the low e is the octave below 10 on the D string, so it's C.